# Sending Email from GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am trying to send all the email listed in my GridView but for somereason, the email does not get sent out.  I am suspecting my Send function (smtpClient.Send(mailMessage); is not working or i am missing something.  Pls help as i have spent so many hours on figuring out this.  thanks

```
protected void chkAll_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    foreach(GridViewRow gr in GridView1.Rows) 
    { 
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)gr.FindControl("chkItem"); 
        if(((CheckBox)sender).Checked) 
            cb.Checked = true; 
        else 
             cb.Checked = false; 
    } 
} 

protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 

    foreach(GridViewRow gr in GridView1.Rows) 
    { 
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)gr.FindControl("chkItem"); 
        if(cb.Checked) 
        { 
            sb.Append(GridView1.DataKeys[gr.RowIndex]["Email"].ToString()); 
            sb.Append(","); 
        } 
    } 

    //Create instance of main mail message class. 
    System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mailMessage=new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(); 

        mailMessage.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(
                   System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
                                 .AppSettings["fromEmailAddress"]); 

        mailMessage.Priority = System.Net.Mail.MailPriority.High; 
        //Text/HTML 
        mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = false; 
        mailMessage.Body = "Hello, here is new email"; 
        mailMessage.Subject = "RCA APPROVAL IS REQUIRED"; 

        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtpClient=new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();

        try 
        { 
            smtpClient.Send(mailMessage); 

            Response.Write("<B>Email Has been sent successfully.</B>"); 
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) 
        { 
            Response.Write(ex.Message); 
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `To` address for the `MailMessage`

You might want to do it like:

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    MailMessage mailMessage=new MailMessage(); 

    foreach(GridViewRow gr in GridView1.Rows) 
    { 
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)gr.FindControl("chkItem"); 
        if(cb.Checked) 
        { 
            //sb.Append(GridView1.DataKeys[gr.RowIndex]["Email"].ToString()); 
            //sb.Append(","); 

            //SETUP THE EMAIL ADDRESSES TO WHICH YOU WANT TO SEND EMAIL
            mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(
                     GridView1.DataKeys[gr.RowIndex]["Email"].ToString()));
        } 
    }
```

Moreover if your `SMTP` server needs authentication you need to provide the `Credentials` also. Or you can put all the settings into `<system.net><mailSettings>` tag in **web.config** as [shown here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/10/432854.aspx) by none other than the mightly **[Scott Gu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/default.aspx)**

Answer (score 0):

It's because your not sending the email to anybody.

Set the value of the mailMessage.To property with the selected addresses on the gridview.

Also, do check your SMTP service, there might be a need to provide credentials and enable SSL.